# Trouble making the while loop work when printing different objects from class

Tags: python

For this module, I have two programs I am using to make this work one called animals.py and another called animalgenerator.py, animals.py defines the class where animalgenerator.py will present the information in a list after getting user input.

Where I have the most trouble is the 'while' loop. I am supposed to get user input about the name of an animal and the type of animal, the user is allowed to have more than one animal. The information about the animals are printed at the end.

Here is an example of what the program should look like:

```
 Welcome    to  the animal  generator!
 This   program creates Animal  objects
 What   type    of  animal  would   you like    to  create? Gecko
 What   is  the animal's    name?   Gordon
 Would  you like    to  add more    animals (y/n)?  y

 What   type    of  animal  would   you like    to  create? Wally
 What   is  the animal's    name?   Walrus
 Would  you like    to  add more    animals (y/n)?  y

 What   type    of  animal  would   you like    to  create? Truman
 What   is  the animal's    name?   Tiger
 Would  you like    to  add more animals    (y/n)?  n

 Animal List
 -----------
 Gordon the Gecko   
 Walrus the Wally   
 Tiger  the Truman
```

My program will only print the last animal's information disregarding any previous animals described. So in this case, my program will only print "Tiger the Truman."

Here is my code for animals.py:

```
class Animal:

    # The __init__ method initializes the attributes

    def __init__(self, name, type):
        self.__name = name
        self.__animal_type = type

    def _animal_type(self, type):
        self.__animal_type = type

    def __name(self, name):
        self.__name = name

    def get_animal_type(self):
        return self.__animal_type

    def get_name(self):
        return self.__name
```

My code for animalgenerator.py is:

```
# This program tests the Animal class.

import animals

print("Welcome to the animal generator!")
print("This program creates Animal objects.")

def main():
    # Get the animal data
    find_info = True
    while(find_info):
        _animal_type = input('\nWhat type of animal would you like to create? ')
        __name = input('What is the animals name? ')
        more_animals = input('Would you like to add more animals (y/n)? ')
        if (more_animals != 'y'):
            find_info = False

    # Create an instance of the animal class
    animal = animals.Animal(_animal_type, __name)

    # Display the data that was entered.
    print('\nAnimal List')
    print('------------- \n' + animal.get_animal_type() + ' the ' + animal.get_name() + '\n')


# Call the main function
main()
```

Comment: Notice that you ask for multiple animals in the while loop but only create and print one animal after the while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your indentation is incorrect, and you are not creating a list.  I suggest:

```
animal_list = []
find_info = True

while(find_info):
    _animal_type = input('\nWhat type of animal would you like to create? ')
    __name = input("What is the animal's name? ")
    more_animals = input('Would you like to add more animals (y/n)? ')
    if (more_animals != 'y'):
        find_info = False

    # Create an instance of the animal class
    animal_list.append(animals.Animal(_animal_type, __name))

print('\nAnimal List')
for animal in animal_list:
    print('------------- \n' + animal.get_animal_type() + ' the ' +  animal.get_name() + '\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

Nice program! I see it's running, asking the user and printing. The only part that's missing is how to remember one animal if the user chooses to name another one.

In the loop, you store the animal's type and name in 2 variables. These variables can only hold 1 name and 1 type. For convenience, you created a custom data type (Animal) which has variables for the name and the type. So now you need a list of Animals to hold the data for many animals. Create an empty list just before you enter the loop. In the loop, create one Animal for each round, store the user's answers and then append that Animal to your list. With python, a list always looks the same and acts the same no matter which objects you store in it.

A list of integers will be created just like a list of Animals. I think that will give you enough clues how to amend your program to be able to store more than 1 animal. (hint: look at the other answers after trying for yourself - that's what makes you learn to program).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't create the animal inside the loop and save it into a list.

```
    animal_list = []
    while(find_info):
        _animal_type = input('\nWhat type of animal would you like to create? ')
        __name = input('What is the animals name? ')


        # Create an instance of the animal class
        animal_list.add(animals.Animal(_animal_type, __name))
        more_animals = input('Would you like to add more animals (y/n)? ')
        if (more_animals != 'y'):
            find_info = False


    # Display the data that was entered.
    print('\nAnimal List')
    for animal in animal_list:
        print('------------- \n' + animal.get_animal_type() + ' the ' + animal.get_name() + '\n')
```